# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array and simple loop:

```
static BigInteger[] dataSet = new BigInteger[] { 100913, 1009139, 10091401, 100914061, 1009140611, 10091406133, 100914061337, 1009140613399 };


 foreach (BigInteger num in dataSet ) {

                BigInteger[] Vector = new BigInteger[num];

                for (BigInteger i = 1; i <= num; i++)  {
                    Vector[i - 1] = i;
                }
            }
```

Can anyone explain why this code returns

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error appears in this line:

```
BigInteger[] Vector = new BigInteger[num];
```

Everything is converted to BigInteger, I do not see the possible reasons.

Will be thankful for help,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: At which line is the error ?

Comment: BigInteger[] Vector = new BigInteger[num];

Comment: `num` is a `BigInteger` but you are using it to initialise the size of your array.

Comment: that's correct, because I want to create arrays at the same size as num

Comment: so where is this a problem ? is there any work-around ?

Comment: Out of curiosity have you considered how much memory an array of 1009140613399 BigIntegers will need? I am not sure what you are doing but you are running serious risks of running out of memory...

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, BigInteger uses (at least) 16 bytes meaning the largest array you want to create here is around 16gb of memory!

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for looking up the numbers. I wasn't sure how big a BigInteger was but figured even that many ints would be massive and it wouldn't be considerably bigger than that. :)

Comment: Also the workaround for the problem you are facing would be to create multiple arrays (or perhaps your own array like class that is backed by private arrays) to store your data but I would definitely think twice before dealing with this much data in memory.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`num` is a `BigInteger` but you are using it to initialise the size of your array:

```
BigInteger[] Vector = new BigInteger[num];
```

The indexer of an array is `int`, meaning that largest size you can create is `int.MaxValue` (2,147,483,647).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to drop idea of using `BigInteger` in the way you use, because you would run out of memory allocating array with value higher than `int.MaxValue`. Arrays and List are limited to `int.MaxValue` for a purpose. Integer would cover your needs in case of array usage in 99.9% cases.

I wonder what are you trying to archive, why do you need such huge arrays filed with just incrementing counter?

In order to make your code compile you need to cast your BigIntegers:

```
         foreach (BigInteger num in dataSet ) {

            BigInteger[] Vector = new BigInteger[(int)num];

            for (BigInteger i = 1; i <= num; i++)  {
                Vector[(int)(i - 1)] = i;
            }
        }
```

But your code most likely fail due to either out of memory or out of range exception, because BigInteger > Integer.